# I have a simple question on 'sort()' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

When I sorted this list,

```
list1 = ['6: baby', '1: dance', '24: doo', '1: lyrics', '6: shark']
list1.sort()
```

output = `['1: dance', '1: lyrics', '24: doo', '6: baby', '6: shark']`
Output is like that. I don't understand why '24: doo' is in the middle, not the back

Comment: That's because of lexicographical order

Comment: It's sorting as a string, not as a number

Comment: "2" is before "6" in the lexicographical order.